# Blocking OS fingerprinting windows server 2008 IIS7

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, security, iis-7

We recently had a 3rd party auditor perform a penetration test on our MS 2008 webserver that uncovered remote OS detection vulnerability. It detected the OS as well as version of IIS.

The Auditors recommended: "if Possible, configure the web server so that it does not present identifiable information in the banners"

I've done quite a bit of research and I could not find any easy way that will allow me to quickly block this information from being detected.

Does anyone know of any way to do this? Is this something that needs to be configured/denied on the server level or web application level within the code?

Comment: what kind of severity did they assign this 'information disclosure' vulnerability?

Answer (score 3):

You can (among other features) remove the `Server:` header from HTTP responses with [UrlScan](http://www.iis.net/download/urlscan). See the [configuration reference](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/938/urlscan-3-reference/) for options.

To remove the `X-Powered-By:` header, in IIS manager, select the **HTTP Response Header** feature, and remove the ASP.NET entry

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately removing http-headers won't help because `nmap` looks at the TCP/IP stack options (things like TTL, IP ID etc), so even after playing with headers `nmap` will still reliably guess your operating system with 99% reliability.

You can (for example) change the TCP/IP packets TTL by editing the registry at

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters]
DefaultTTL
```

And make it `64` to fake a linux, but nmap is not that easily fooled.

Check out this question at `security.stackexchange` for more info https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70853/how-nmap-guesses-the-operating-system